# Create dynamic columns with sequential counter

Tags: sql, postgresql

In an export scenario I am creating spreadsheets with a user+user roles export like this:

```
|User Name  |Role_1  |Role_2     |Role_3  |
|superuser  |somerole|anotherrole|goodrole|
|anotheruser|somerole|goodrole   |        |
```

The "ragged aligned" roles are created sequential from 1 to x-number of all assigned roles (not the number of roles overall).

This is a simplified example:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ez4CyVxjc8ZRjTnfLGPHH/5

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT,
    name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
    user_id INT,
    role_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
    role_id INT,
    name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO users (user_id, name) VALUES (1, 'superuser'), (2, 'anotherusers');

INSERT INTO roles (role_id, name) VALUES (1, 'somerole'), (2, 'anotherrole'), (3, 'goodrole');

INSERT INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3), (2,1),(2,3);
```

Current approach with one JSON field:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT json_agg(roles.name ORDER BY roles.role_id ASC) as roles 
  FROM user_roles
  INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id=roles.role_id
  WHERE user_roles.user_id=users.user_id
) roles ON True;
```

Currently I am putting all roles in a JSON field and unpack it on the application level. However I would like to achieve the ragged alignment format already on the query level. Is this possible with PostgreSQL query magic, or by facilitating (plpgsql) functions?

Another acceptable result for me would to populate a JSON Object with all columns included in each row. Missing values would be null.

So instead of

```
1   "superuser" "["somerole", "anotherrole", "goodrole"]"
2   "anotherusers"  "["somerole", "goodrole"]"
```

It could yield:

```
1   "superuser" "["somerole", "anotherrole", "goodrole"]"
2   "anotherusers"  "["somerole", "goodrole", "null"]"
```

The problem I am trying to solve is, that I need to know the maximum number of user roles in the starting row when I put it in the spreadsheet. I could put this in two different queries/requests on the application level - but I would rather have the column in a fixed format.

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns, so you have to decide on the maximum number of roles in advance.  However, instead of unpacking JSON, perhaps you would find an array easier to work with at the application level.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is true. I am fine using the JSON response thought. Maybe someone has done this before with plpgsql functions or there is a extension available. Postgres  surprises sometimes ;)